# Flask resource in object html

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm in /statistics/id.

I have a resource in my flask view :

```
@app.route('/statistics2/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST']):
     quotation_title = db.get_quotation_by_session_parameter(id, 'number_questions')
     return render_template('statistics2.html', quotation_title = quotation_title)
```

I want to call this resource in my object html tag.

I do that:

```
<object id="content" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" data="statistics" ></object>
```

In the data attribute I want to indicate statistics/id but I don't know how can I retrieve the current id

For example: With the id 6, I'm in /statistics/6 and I want to show in my object html in data attribute statistics2/6.

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `id` from `quotation_title` variable that you pass to template.

Like so `{{ quotation_title.id }}`